# Data restore procedure failed in OrientDB

Tags: database, database-connection, scalability, database-restore, orientdb

Last night I received the following error after inserting ~500k records:

> 2014-07-03 22:10:50:056 SEVE Internal server error:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot get allocation information
>   for database 'pumpup' because it is not a disk-based database
>   [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]

My OrientDB `server.sh` froze, so I rebooted my computer. Now when I try to access the database, I get the following output from `server.sh`:

```
2014-07-04 13:52:35:331 INFO OrientDB Server v1.7.3 is active. [OServer]
2014-07-04 13:52:38:784 WARN segment file 'database.ocf' was not closed correctly last time [OSingleFileSegment]
2014-07-04 13:52:38:879 WARN Storage pumpup was not closed properly. Will try to restore from write ahead log. [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2014-07-04 13:52:38:879 INFO Looking for last checkpoint... [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2014-07-04 13:52:38:879 INFO Checkpoints are absent, the restore will start from the beginning. [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2014-07-04 13:52:38:880 INFO Data restore procedure is started. [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2014-07-04 13:53:15:080 INFO Heap memory is low apply batch of operations are read from WAL. [OLocalPaginatedStorage]Exception during storage data restore.
null
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.restoreWALBatch(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:1842)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.restoreFrom(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:1802)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.restoreFromBegging(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:1772)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.restoreFromWAL(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:1611)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.restoreIfNeeded(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:1578)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.open(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:245)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.raw.ODatabaseRaw.open(ODatabaseRaw.java:100)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.open(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:49)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordAbstract.open(ODatabaseRecordAbstract.java:268)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.open(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:49)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.openDatabase(OServer.java:557)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.command.OServerCommandAuthenticatedDbAbstract.authenticate(OServerCommandAuthenticatedDbAbstract.java:126)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.command.OServerCommandAuthenticatedDbAbstract.beforeExecute(OServerCommandAuthenticatedDbAbstract.java:87)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.command.get.OServerCommandGetConnect.beforeExecute(OServerCommandGetConnect.java:46)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.service(ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.java:173)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.execute(ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.java:572)
-> com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:45)
2014-07-04 13:53:15:082 SEVE Internal server error:
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot open local storage '/Users/gsquare567/Databases/orientdb-community-1.7.3/databases/pumpup' with mode=rw
--> java.lang.NullPointerException [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]
```

When I try to connect every subsequent time, I get the following:

> --> com.orientechnologies.common.concur.lock.OLockException: File '/Users/gsquare567/Databases/orientdb-community-1.7.3/databases/pumpup/database.ocf'
>   is locked by another process, maybe the database is in use by another
>   process. Use the remote mode with a OrientDB server to allow multiple
>   access to the same database. [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]

I can't connect to the database. I'm going to update from `1.7.3` to `1.7.4`, recreate the database, and try again. For now, here's some output from `dserver.sh` as it seems to be trying to perform a data restore procedure:

```
2014-07-04 14:01:09:168 INFO [192.168.1.8]:2434 [orientdb] [3.2.2] Address[192.168.1.8]:2434 is STARTED [LifecycleService]
2014-07-04 14:01:09:198 INFO [192.168.1.8]:2434 [orientdb] [3.2.2] Initializing cluster partition table first arrangement... [InternalPartitionService]
2014-07-04 14:01:09:212 INFO [node1404496844581] found no previous messages in queue orientdb.node.node1404496844581.response [OHazelcastDistributedMessageService]
2014-07-04 14:01:09:230 WARN [node1404496844581] opening database 'pumpup'... [OHazelcastPlugin]
2014-07-04 14:01:09:231 INFO [node1404496844581] loaded database configuration from disk: /Users/gsquare567/Databases/orientdb-community-1.7.3/config/default-distributed-db-config.json [OHazelcastPlugin]
2014-07-04 14:01:09:238 INFO updated distributed configuration for database: pumpup:
----------
{
  "autoDeploy":true,
  "hotAlignment":false,
  "readQuorum":1,
  "writeQuorum":2,
  "failureAvailableNodesLessQuorum":false,
  "readYourWrites":true,"clusters":{
    "internal":{
},
    "index":{
},
    "*":{
  "servers":["<NEW_NODE>"]
}
    },
  "version":0
}
---------- [OHazelcastPlugin]
2014-07-04 14:01:09:243 INFO updated distributed configuration for database: pumpup:
----------
{
  "version":0,
  "autoDeploy":true,
  "hotAlignment":false,
  "readQuorum":1,
  "writeQuorum":2,
  "failureAvailableNodesLessQuorum":false,
  "readYourWrites":true,"clusters":{
    "internal":null,
    "index":null,
    "*":{
  "servers":["<NEW_NODE>"]
}
    }
}
---------- [OHazelcastPlugin]
2014-07-04 14:01:09:243 INFO Saving distributed configuration file for database 'pumpup' to: /Users/gsquare567/Databases/orientdb-community-1.7.3/databases/pumpup/distributed-config.json [OHazelcastPlugin]
2014-07-04 14:01:09:246 INFO [node1404496844581] adding node 'node1404496844581' in partition: db=pumpup [*] [OHazelcastDistributedDatabase]
2014-07-04 14:01:09:246 INFO updated distributed configuration for database: pumpup:
----------
{
  "version":1,
  "autoDeploy":true,
  "hotAlignment":false,
  "readQuorum":1,
  "writeQuorum":2,
  "failureAvailableNodesLessQuorum":false,
  "readYourWrites":true,"clusters":{
    "internal":null,
    "index":null,
    "*":{
  "servers":["<NEW_NODE>","node1404496844581"]
}
    }
}
---------- [OHazelcastPlugin]
2014-07-04 14:01:09:247 INFO Saving distributed configuration file for database 'pumpup' to: /Users/gsquare567/Databases/orientdb-community-1.7.3/databases/pumpup/distributed-config.json [OHazelcastPlugin]
2014-07-04 14:01:09:247 INFO [node1404496844581] received added status node1404496844581.pumpup=OFFLINE [OHazelcastPlugin]
2014-07-04 14:01:09:249 INFO [node1404496844581] found no previous messages in queue orientdb.node.node1404496844581.pumpup.request [OHazelcastDistributedMessageService]
2014-07-04 14:01:09:288 WARN segment file 'database.ocf' was not closed correctly last time [OSingleFileSegment]
2014-07-04 14:01:09:378 WARN Storage pumpup was not closed properly. Will try to restore from write ahead log. [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2014-07-04 14:01:09:378 INFO Looking for last checkpoint... [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2014-07-04 14:01:09:378 INFO Checkpoints are absent, the restore will start from the beginning. [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2014-07-04 14:01:09:379 INFO Data restore procedure is started. [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2014-07-04 14:01:35:724 INFO Heap memory is low apply batch of operations are read from WAL. [OLocalPaginatedStorage]Exception during storage data restore.
null
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.restoreWALBatch(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:1842)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.restoreFrom(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:1802)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.restoreFromBegging(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:1772)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.restoreFromWAL(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:1611)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.restoreIfNeeded(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:1578)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.open(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:245)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.raw.ODatabaseRaw.open(ODatabaseRaw.java:100)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.open(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:49)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordAbstract.open(ODatabaseRecordAbstract.java:268)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.open(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:49)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.openDatabase(OServer.java:557)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.initDatabaseInstance(OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.java:283)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.setOnline(OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.java:295)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.loadDistributedDatabases(OHazelcastPlugin.java:742)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.startup(OHazelcastPlugin.java:194)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.registerPlugins(OServer.java:720)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:241)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain.main(OServerMain.java:32)Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot open local storage '/Users/gsquare567/Databases/orientdb-community-1.7.3/databases/pumpup' with mode=rw
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.open(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:251)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.raw.ODatabaseRaw.open(ODatabaseRaw.java:100)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.open(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:49)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordAbstract.open(ODatabaseRecordAbstract.java:268)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.open(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:49)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.openDatabase(OServer.java:557)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.initDatabaseInstance(OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.java:283)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.setOnline(OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.java:295)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.loadDistributedDatabases(OHazelcastPlugin.java:742)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.startup(OHazelcastPlugin.java:194)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.registerPlugins(OServer.java:720)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:241)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain.main(OServerMain.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.restoreWALBatch(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:1842)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.restoreFrom(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:1802)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.restoreFromBegging(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:1772)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.restoreFromWAL(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:1611)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.restoreIfNeeded(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:1578)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.open(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:245)
    ... 12 more

2014-07-04 14:01:39:184 INFO [192.168.1.8]:2434 [orientdb] [3.2.2] memory.used=1.3G, memory.free=155.9M, memory.total=1.4G, memory.max=1.8G, memory.used/total=89.32%, memory.used/max=71.63%, load.process=37.00%, load.system=41.00%, load.systemAverage=170.00%, thread.count=59, thread.peakCount=59, event.q.size=0, executor.q.async.size=0, executor.q.client.size=0, executor.q.operation.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0, executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0, executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operation.size=0, executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0, operations.remote.size=0, operations.running.size=0, proxy.count=5, clientEndpoint.count=0, connection.active.count=0, connection.count=0 [HealthMonitor]
2014-07-04 14:02:09:195 INFO [192.168.1.8]:2434 [orientdb] [3.2.2] memory.used=1.3G, memory.free=155.2M, memory.total=1.4G, memory.max=1.8G, memory.used/total=89.37%, memory.used/max=71.68%, load.process=0.00%, load.system=4.00%, load.systemAverage=162.00%, thread.count=59, thread.peakCount=59, event.q.size=0, executor.q.async.size=0, executor.q.client.size=0, executor.q.operation.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0, executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0, executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operation.size=0, executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0, operations.remote.size=0, operations.running.size=0, proxy.count=5, clientEndpoint.count=0, connection.active.count=0, connection.count=0 [HealthMonitor]
2014-07-04 14:02:39:207 INFO [192.168.1.8]:2434 [orientdb] [3.2.2] memory.used=1.3G, memory.free=149.3M, memory.total=1.4G, memory.max=1.8G, memory.used/total=89.77%, memory.used/max=72.00%, load.process=0.00%, load.system=5.00%, load.systemAverage=124.00%, thread.count=61, thread.peakCount=61, event.q.size=0, executor.q.async.size=0, executor.q.client.size=0, executor.q.operation.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0, executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0, executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operation.size=0, executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0, operations.remote.size=0, operations.running.size=0, proxy.count=5, clientEndpoint.count=0, connection.active.count=0, connection.count=0 [HealthMonitor]
2014-07-04 14:03:09:218 INFO [192.168.1.8]:2434 [orientdb] [3.2.2] memory.used=1.3G, memory.free=149.2M, memory.total=1.4G, memory.max=1.8G, memory.used/total=89.78%, memory.used/max=72.00%, load.process=0.00%, load.system=6.00%, load.systemAverage=151.00%, thread.count=61, thread.peakCount=61, event.q.size=0, executor.q.async.size=0, executor.q.client.size=0, executor.q.operation.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0, executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0, executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operation.size=0, executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0, operations.remote.size=0, operations.running.size=0, proxy.count=5, clientEndpoint.count=0, connection.active.count=0, connection.count=0 [HealthMonitor]
```

**EDIT**

Here is my OrientDB `info`:

```
CLUSTERS
----------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------+---------+-----------------+
 NAME                                         |   ID  | TYPE                | DATASEG | RECORDS         |
----------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------+---------+-----------------+
 default                                      |     3 | PHYSICAL            |      -1 |               0 |
 e                                            |    10 | PHYSICAL            |      -1 |               0 |
 index                                        |     1 | PHYSICAL            |      -1 |               4 |
 internal                                     |     0 | PHYSICAL            |      -1 |               3 |
 manindex                                     |     2 | PHYSICAL            |      -1 |               1 |
 ofunction                                    |     7 | PHYSICAL            |      -1 |               0 |
 orids                                        |     6 | PHYSICAL            |      -1 |               0 |
 orole                                        |     4 | PHYSICAL            |      -1 |               3 |
 oschedule                                    |     8 | PHYSICAL            |      -1 |               0 |
 ouser                                        |     5 | PHYSICAL            |      -1 |               3 |
 post                                         |    12 | PHYSICAL            |      -1 |         1312295 |
 user                                         |    11 | PHYSICAL            |      -1 |          205795 |
 v                                            |     9 | PHYSICAL            |      -1 |               0 |
----------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------+---------+-----------------+
 TOTAL = 13                                                                 |         |         1518104 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+

CLASSES
----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
 NAME                                         | SUPERCLASS                         | CLUSTERS   | RECORDS        |
----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
 E                                            |                                    | 10         |              0 |
 OFunction                                    |                                    | 7          |              0 |
 OIdentity                                    |                                    | -          |              0 |
 ORestricted                                  |                                    | -          |              0 |
 ORIDs                                        |                                    | 6          |              0 |
 ORole                                        | OIdentity                          | 4          |              3 |
 OSchedule                                    |                                    | 8          |              0 |
 OTriggered                                   |                                    | -          |              0 |
 OUser                                        | OIdentity                          | 5          |              3 |
 ParseObject                                  |                                    | -          |              0 |
 Post                                         | ParseObject                        | 12         |        1312295 |
 User                                         | ParseObject                        | 11         |         205795 |
 V                                            |                                    | 9          |              0 |
----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
 TOTAL = 13                                                                                              1518096 |
----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+

INDEXES
----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------------------+----------------+------------+
 NAME                                         | TYPE       |         CLASS         |     FIELDS     | RECORDS    |
----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------------------+----------------+------------+
 dictionary                                   | DICTIONARY |                       |                |          0 |
 ORole.name                                   | UNIQUE     | ORole                 | name           |          3 |
 OUser.name                                   | UNIQUE     | OUser                 | name           |          3 |
 Post.objectId                                | UNIQUE_... | Post                  | objectId       |    1312295 |
 User.objectId                                | UNIQUE_... | User                  | objectId       |     205795 |
----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------------------+----------------+------------+
 TOTAL = 5                                                                                               1518096 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```